# jenkins (or groovy) using pom.xml from previous execution

Tags: multithreading, groovy, jenkins, pom.xml

I have a **Jenkins job** which receives as parameter a svn url to a **maven project**. It executes **groovy scripts** and some steps like mvn package, mvn deploy,... but I am finding a problem, when I launch the job for first time everything is fine, however when I execute it a second time and I change the input project, **Jenkins or groovy seem to be using the previous execution's pom.xml**, I mean, when I try to retrieve in groovy the artifactId from the projects's pom I always get the artifactId of the first project, it doesn't matter how many times I launch the job or if I do wipe out the current workspace, it will always return the first pom values.

The groovy code I use to read the pom.xml values is:

```
def thr = Thread.currentThread() //This line may be the problem?
def currentBuild = thr?.executable
def pomMAIN = currentBuild.getParent().getModules().toArray().size()-1
def mavenVer = currentBuild.getParent().getModules().toArray()[pomMAIN].getVersion()
def mavenArtifactId = currentBuild.getParent().getModules().toArray()[pomMAIN].getArtifactId()
def mavenGroupId = currentBuild.getParent().getModules().toArray()[pomMAIN].getGroupId()
```

I have tried to delete and create the job again but the behaviour is always the same, it only gets the right pom during the first execution.

**Is there a way to clean up the job/groovy data?**

EDIT 06/07/2015:

My job retrieves the svn code using the section **Source Code Management:** [image]

The Check-out Strategy should be enough to be sure that the code is updated, but I have also checked the job workspace to ensure the pom is the right one and it is.

Comment: Have you tried telling jenkins to clean the workspace before it begins execution? You may need to install https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin to help with this

Comment: I have tried to manually clean the workspace and didn't work but I will give a try to that plugin, hope it helps

Comment: The plugin didn't solve the problem

Comment: How do you retrieve your maven project from the svn repository? Are you sure that your files are updated ?

Comment: I have updated the question with this info, but I think it is not the problem, since I check the workspace and find the right pom, but groovy still read values from the previous build. I suspect that somehow `thr = Thread.currentThread()` is causing the error because the thread is not being updated, but I don't know how to clean/update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, now I have a groovy script at the begining of the job that refreshs it:

```
def jobNameToRefresh = "nameOfMyJob";
def hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance;

for(job in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.items) {   
    if (job.name == jobNameToRefresh) {
        def configXMLFile = job.getConfigFile();
        def file = configXMLFile.getFile();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        job.updateByXml(new StreamSource(is));
        job.save();
        return true        
    }      
}
```

And, in the end of the job, I remove the folder "modules" with a shell script that basically does:

```
cd..
rm -r modules
```